# Android layout displaying both list items and some textviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I try to show name and author of the book at the top and list some reviews about that book in Android.

I have used the `ArrayAdapter` to list the reviews therefore I couldn't understand where should I put the `name-author textview` objects in the layout.

My layout and related java code are at below. I consider that there should be another view, it should contains `name-author textview` objects and include the `list_item layout` but I am not sure because it is my first android app.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        setListAdapter(new ReviewListAdaptor(
                ReviewListActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, reviewList));

 }

private class ReviewListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Review> {
        private ArrayList<Review> reviewList;
        public ReviewListAdaptor(Context context,int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Review> items) {
                  super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                  this.reviewList = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }
                Review o = reviewList.get(position);
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                tt.setText(o.header);
                bt.setText(o.message);
                return v;
        }
   }
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/toptext" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />  

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:textSize="10dp"
             />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your task, you have three choices:

1. Let the book and author be shown in the title of the Activity with setTitle()

In the other two cases don't use the ListActivity class, as your Activity will be so much more.

1. Have a book and author header that's docked (doesn't scroll): in this case, your Activity's Layout will look somethink like this:

   [Header items]

And you have to get a reference to the list (and header items), and set the adapter of that list (and set content of header items):

```
ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
myList.setAdapter([your adapter instance]);
```

1. You want a header that scrolls away and gives space to the list. In this case, you cant use ListView, as scrolling inside scrolling is not supported in Android. I won't post code, you probably dont want this. If you do, you have to start with a scroll view, add a linear layout, add your header inside that linear layout, and a placeholder (linear layout) for the list items. Then inflate a list item view for every data item, and add the elements to the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new View with both textviews a list with the reviews using your custom adaper and put them both in another custom adapter using [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-adapter) project. Read the .txt and you should be able to solve your problem.